# Sub + Verb + Obj + V-ing

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I found a sentence like below in my grammar book.

"Did you have problems finding our house?"

Don't you think there is supposed to be a preposition before "finding" ?

Like "Did you have any problems with finding our house?" or "Did you have any problems about finding our house?"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatically, there is no preposition there, and your grammar book is correct.  [We say "problems *verb*-ing" or "trouble *verb*-ing" much more than we use *with* or *in* or *about* or anything else](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=problems+finding%2Cproblems+with+finding%2Cproblems+about+finding%2Cproblems+in+finding&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cproblems%20finding%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cproblems%20with%20finding%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cproblems%20about%20finding%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cproblems%20in%20finding%3B%2Cc0), although those constructions are used sometimes too.

You can think of "problems finding our house" as "problems *while in the process of* finding our house".  "Problems *with* finding our house" is perfectly understandable, but less idiomatic.  "Problems *about* finding our house" doesn't quite make sense - *about* usually means something like "regarding the subject of"; you might say "Here is a math problem about calculating sales taxes", but "problems about finding our house" sounds like puzzles that you have to solve to find our house.

Comment: This is interesting. Other words that work this way are _experience_, _challenge_, _success_; but not _question_, _concern_ or _solution_. I think the criterion is that the word refers to the experience (not just one aspect of it), and the participle clause specifies what the experience was. _Problem_ at first sight appears to be an aspect of the experience, not the experience itself; but in fact we use it to mean the whole experience: "Finding the house was a problem".

Comment: So, if I say "I have some problems speaking fluently" , it will be grammatically correct.

Comment: @NevzatDoğukanErbek Correct!

Answer (score 0):

The sentence

> "Did you have problems **finding** our house?"

is valid with or without a preposition, just as this is valid:

> "Did you have (any) problems **eating** at that restaraunt?"

I think using a prepositon with either example would sound verbose.